# How can I DRY out this php

Tags: php

I have this function that works really well for what I want it to do:

```
function textStyles($prefix, $position, $type){
    $title = get_sub_field($prefix . '_' . $position . '_font_' . $type);
    $titles = get_sub_field($prefix . '_' . $position . '_font_' . $type);
    $titleNG = get_field($prefix . '_' . $position . '_font_' . $type);
    $titleOption = get_field($prefix . '_' . $position . '_font_' . $type, 'options');
    $titleTheme = get_theme_mod( 'hero_text_' . $type, 0 );
    
    return $title ?: $titles ?: $titleNG ?: $titleOption ?: $titleTheme;
}
```

But then to use it, I'm doing things like this:

```
$titleSize = textStyles($sepPrefix, 'title', 'size');
$titleColor = textStyles($sepPrefix, 'title', 'color');
$titleWeight = textStyles($sepPrefix, 'title', 'weight');
$titleAlign = textStyles($sepPrefix, 'title', 'alignment');

$titleClass = $titleSize . ' ' . $titleColor . ' ' . $titleWeight . ' ' . $titleAlign;

$introSize = textStyles($sepPrefix, 'intro', 'size');
$introColor = textStyles($sepPrefix, 'intro', 'color');
$introWeight = textStyles($sepPrefix, 'intro', 'weight');
$introAlign = textStyles($sepPrefix, 'intro', 'alignment');

$introClass = $introSize . ' ' . $introColor . ' ' . $introWeight . ' ' . $introAlign;
```

I'm sure there must be a DRY way to do this, but I'm not even sure how to search for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
function textClass($prefix, $position, $attrs)
{
    $classes = [];
    foreach ($attrs as $attr) {
        $classes[] = textStyles($prefix, $position, $attr);
    }
    return implode(' ', $classes);
}
```

And then call it with the attributes you want like so:

```
$introClass = textClass($sepPrefix, 'intro', ['size', 'color', 'weight', 'alignment']);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works a charm, and lets me specific less parameters as I sometimes need to do. Thank you!